# Yielding infinitely for WWW object when internet connection fails

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the WWW class in order to send http requests and after creating the request I'm waiting for it to complete using a coroutine. The coroutine is calling "yield return www" and logs the result.
I've noticed that when the internet connection is down, the coroutine never returns. Is there some sort of a timeout mechanism in WWW?

Thanks

Comment: Timeout seems to be 60s, did you try something like that: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/566671/any-way-around-www-timeout-on-android.html?

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout mechanism in WWW, but you can implement it on your own.

Since the www object is yielding, you can check how long is has been running and decide if it is timeout.

You can put the yield return www in a function, AsyncSend() for example.

```
public IEnumerator AsyncSend()
{
    ...
    yield return www;
    ...
}
```

Now you get a Coroutine by invoking the above function.

```
IEnumerator coroutine = AsyncSend();
StartCoroutine(coroutine);   //http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html
```

In the Update(), you can check if it is timeout.

```
void Update()
{
    ...
    //timeout
    if (...)
    {
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);  //http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html
        www.Dispose();   //http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.Dispose.html
    }
    ...
}
```